# Using Sphinx's autodoc with Django

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I can't get Sphinx to generate automatic documentation for my Django project from the apps' `models.py` files. When I run `make html` I get the warning

```
WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document u'modules/models'
```

My directory setup is:

```
.../www/proj/manage.py
             /proj/settings.py
                  /urls.py
                  ...
             /myapp1/models.py
                   /views.py
                   ...
             /docs/Makefile
                  /build/
                  /modules/models.rst
                  /source/conf.py
                         /index.rst
                         ...
```

The relevant bit of `index.rst` is:

```
Documentation for qdb
=====================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   modules/models



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

`modules/models.rst` is:

```
Models
======
.. automodule:: myapp1.models
    :members:
```

and the bit from `conf.py` is:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
```

I've also tried:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../..'))
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'qdb.settings'
```

but this isn't working either. How can I tell Sphinx where to find `modules/models.rst`?

[I'm on Python 2.7, Django 1.8, Sphinx 1.3.1]

Comment: It is an old question but just have read it, I think it is because your index.rst file is not at the same level as modules folder, you need to specify ../modules/models rather than modules/models